# trunk between two switches on different network

Tags: cisco, switch, trunk

I have a trunk setup between the 172.16.64.2 and 172.16.128.2 switches, but I can't ping them.  I can only ping their default gateways which is their .1 on the router.  What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: when I do a show ip route, 172.16.128.2 switch shows  C 172.16.128.0 is directly connected, and vice versa on the 172.16.64.2 switch.  Seems like they only know about their network.  I have RIP on the router advertising both networks.  Network 172.16.0.0

Comment: You need to edit the question to include the network device configurations. We cannot simply guess where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Each client (laptop) needs to have a route to the other network, usually there's just a default gateway - in this case this must be `172.16.x.1`.
2. The router *gw-test* needs to route between the networks. Since there's only a single router and both networks are directly attached, there's no need for setting static routes or using a routing protocol (which exchanges routes between routers).
3. The network `172.16.0.0`(/16?) cannot be used between the networks because both subnets belong to this network.
4. The dotted link in the diagram makes no sense unless you separate both networks/subnets into VLANs and use VLAN trunks between the switches and to the router.

Comment: 1.  Ok, the laptops in the 172.16.64.0 have the gateway 172.16.64.1, and the ones in 172.16.128.0 have gateway 172.16.128.1

Comment: 2.  Ok, I Understood

Comment: 3.  The network is actually /18 255.255.192.0

Comment: 4.  So do I need to create 172.16.64.2 VLAN 2, and 172.16.128.2 VLAN 3?  Would this work?

Comment: 3. `172.16.0.0/18` would be a third network. 4. Yes, this would work with all respective ports in those VLANs and if the router can handle it.

Comment: I made VLAN 64 on the 172.16.64.2 (port 22) and VLAN 128 (port 22) on the 172.16.128.2.  Do I connect cable from port 22 to 22?

Comment: On the 172.16.64.2 switch, I have interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 64
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk

Comment: On the 172.16.128.2 switch, I have interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 128
 switchport trunk native vlan 10
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk

Comment: I have cable going from port 10 from both switches to each other.

Comment: I can't make sense of this, sorry. You should add this info and the configs to your question.

Comment: I have default gateway for 172.16.64.2 switch as 172.16.64.1, and for 172.16.128.2 switch default gateway as 172.16.128.1.  I'll post the configs.

Comment: I can ping 172.16.128.1 from the 172.16.64.2 switch

Comment: I can ping both switches now.  I turned off ip routing, and added their default gateways.

Comment: Everything is working the way I want to now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're satisfied you should accept the answer.